# Match triggerAction() with Dynamic dialogAction button

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, chatbot

So, I'm trying to move a button click to a triggerAction() instead of the beginDialogAction() that I have implemented right now but I can't seem to find the right regex pattern to match and route this action button click:

`UniversalBot("*") routing "action?loadreference-pt=FT2018/52" from "emulator"`

Bear in mind that the last part is dynamic so it would be always like:

`"action?loadreference-pt=[INVOICE_NUMBER]"`

Right now, this works just fine but I would prefer with triggerAction() to override customPrompts():

`bot.triggerAction('loadreference-pt', '/loadreference-pt');`

I've tried with a regexp like:

`.triggerAction({ matches: /action?loadreference.pt=\w+/ });`

But it's not working.
Could someone help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "?" means that the preceding phrase (action) is optional. So, depending on what you were intending, if you just wanted to match the "?", you need to escape the ? (\?) or, if you really meant to make matching "action" optional, you still need to match the "?" in the target.
So action\?loadreference.pt=\w+ or action?\?loadreference.pt=\w+

Comment: I've tried like  /action\?loadreference-pt=\w+/ and it stil isn't recognized byt the UniversalBot router.

Comment: any other suggestion?